# What is this non numeric matrix extent error in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, plot, mean

Im trying to apply a function onto my list but it returns this error

"non numeric matrix extent error"

here's my code

the error occurs in the last few lines
the code works fine up till the end, and because of this, im unable to plot my graphs 
I've searched online but couldnt find anything that helps, and I cant see what's wrong with the code

```
#Question 1
set.seed(10000)

v <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)

lyst <- list()

for(i in v)
{
  for(j in v)
  {
    elementname <- paste0(as.character(i),"-",as.character(j))
    print(elementname)
    lyst[[elementname]] <- rgamma(10000,i,j)
  }
}
#Question 2
pdf("Question2.pdf",width = 20, height = 10)
par(mfcol=c(7,7))
for(x in names(lyst))
{
  hist(lyst[[x]],
       xlab = "Value",
       main = paste("Alpha-Lambda:",x))
}
dev.off()

#Question 3
theoretical_mean <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=7,dimnames=list(as.character(v), as.character(v)))
theoretical_var <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=7,dimnames=list(as.character(v), as.character(v)))
for (i in 1:7)
{
  for (j in 1:7)
  {
    theoretical_mean[j,i] <- as.character(v[i]/v[j])
    theoretical_var[j,i] <- as.character(v[i]/(v[j]^2))
  }
}

sample_mean <-lapply(lyst, mean)
sample_mean <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sample_mean),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sample_mean <- round(sample_mean,digits = 3)
sample_mean <- data.matrix(sample_mean, rownames.force = NA)

sample_var <-lapply(lyst, var)

sample_var <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sample_var),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sample_var <- round(sample_var,digits = 3)
sample_var <- data.matrix(sample_var, rownames.force = NA)

theor_sample_mean <- matrix(paste(theoretical_mean, sample_mean, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames = dimnames(theoretical_var))
theor_sample_var <- matrix(paste(theoretical_var, sample_var, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames= dimnames(theoretical_var))

sink("Q3.txt")
cat("Theoretical Mean vs. Sample Mean:\n")
print(as.table(theor_sample_mean))
cat("\n")
cat("Theoretical Variance vs. Sample Variance:\n")
print(as.table(theor_sample_var))
sink()

#Question 4
nmean <- function(x)
{
  m <- matrix(nrow=nrow(x))
  for (j in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    v <- c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    {
      v <- c(v,mean(x[1:i,j]))
    }
    m <- cbind(m,v)
  }
  m <- m[,-1]
  colnames(m) <- colnames(x)
  rownames(m) <- NULL
  return(m)
}
sequentialMeans <- lapply(lyst,nmean)

pdf("Question4.pdf",width=15,height=10)
for (i in 1:7)
{
  for (j in 1:7)
  {
    plot(y=sequentialMeans[[i]][,j],x=1:10000,xlab="n value",ylab="Values", main=paste("Alpha-Lambda:",colnames(lyst[[i]])[j]),type="l")
  }
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the data format of the input for the `nmean` function according to the lines

```
nmean <- function(x)
{
  m <- matrix(nrow=nrow(x))
  for (j in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    v <- c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    {
      v <- c(v,mean(x[1:i,j]))
    }
    m <- cbind(m,v)
  }
  m <- m[,-1]
  colnames(m) <- colnames(x)
  rownames(m) <- NULL
  return(m)
}
```

is a matrix and you want feed it vectors of gamma-distributed values as specified in the following lines

```
lyst <- list()

for(i in v)
{
  for(j in v)
  {
    elementname <- paste0(as.character(i),"-",as.character(j))
    print(elementname)
    lyst[[elementname]] <- rgamma(10000,i,j)
  }
}
```

For `x` that have type vector, the function `ncol(x)`and `nrow(x)`return `NULL`. Besides, there is also no application of `ncol(x)` possible.

If you want to save your approach you need to either think about transforming your data into matrix format or alternatively, use the vector format but use the vector-compatible functions `length(x)` for the length of the vector and `names(lyst)` for the names.

---

Update:

The code in the comments works but you got to change the `lapply`-statement as you now have a matrix that you can use as input for the `nmean` function directly. The following code works for generating `sampleMeans` and avoids the original error message of your question. In order to cut down runtime it only takes 100 samples.

```
#Question 1
set.seed(10000)

v <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)

lyst <- list()

for(i in v)
{
  for(j in v)
  {
    elementname <- paste0(as.character(i),"-",as.character(j))
    print(elementname)
    lyst[[elementname]] <- rgamma(100,i,j)
  }
}
#Question 2
pdf("Question2.pdf",width = 20, height = 10)
par(mfcol=c(7,7))
for(x in names(lyst))
{
  hist(lyst[[x]],
       xlab = "Value",
       main = paste("Alpha-Lambda:",x))
}
dev.off()

#Question 3
theoretical_mean <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=7,dimnames=list(as.character(v), as.character(v)))
theoretical_var <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=7,dimnames=list(as.character(v), as.character(v)))
for (i in 1:7)
{
  for (j in 1:7)
  {
    theoretical_mean[j,i] <- as.character(v[i]/v[j])
    theoretical_var[j,i] <- as.character(v[i]/(v[j]^2))
  }
}

sample_mean <-lapply(lyst, mean)
sample_mean <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sample_mean),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sample_mean <- round(sample_mean,digits = 3)
sample_mean <- data.matrix(sample_mean, rownames.force = NA)

sample_var <-lapply(lyst, var)

sample_var <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sample_var),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sample_var <- round(sample_var,digits = 3)
sample_var <- data.matrix(sample_var, rownames.force = NA)

theor_sample_mean <- matrix(paste(theoretical_mean, sample_mean, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames = dimnames(theoretical_var))
theor_sample_var <- matrix(paste(theoretical_var, sample_var, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames= dimnames(theoretical_var))

sink("Q3.txt")
cat("Theoretical Mean vs. Sample Mean:\n")
print(as.table(theor_sample_mean))
cat("\n")
cat("Theoretical Variance vs. Sample Variance:\n")
print(as.table(theor_sample_var))
sink()

lyst = matrix(unlist(lyst), ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE) 
colnames(lyst) = c("100-0.1","100-0.5","100-1","100-2","100-5","100-10","100-100")
#Question 4
nmean <- function(x)
{
  m <- matrix(nrow=nrow(x))
  for (j in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    v <- c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    {
      v <- c(v,mean(x[1:i,j]))
    }
    m <- cbind(m,v)
  }
  m <- m[,-1]
  colnames(m) <- colnames(x)
  rownames(m) <- NULL
  return(m)
}
sequentialMeans <- nmean(lyst)
```

Note also that you need to adjust the code for Q4, that is, the plot generation. The following code works.

```
pdf("Question4.pdf",width=15,height=10)
    for (i in 1:7)
    {
      for (j in 1:7)
      {
        plot(y=sequentialMeans[,j],x=1:700,xlab="n value",ylab="Values", main=paste("Alpha-Lambda:",colnames(lyst[,j]),type="l"))
      }
    }
    dev.off()
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: so something like this ```lyst <- matrix(unlist(lyst), ncol = 7, byrow = T)```

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility. But be aware that you stil need to supply `colnames(lyst)` prior for your function to work!

Comment: hmm I added in ```colnames(lyst) <- c("100-0.1","100-0.5","100-1","100-2","100-5","100-10","100-100")``` yet it still returned the same error for me

Comment: @user12197328 I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: thanks for the big reply, appreciate the help, but from that it did fix the error I was receiving, but now its giving me another error ```Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  object 'sequentialMeans' not found```

Comment: Running the code I gave above yields no error messages for me. Try restarting your R session with Shift + Strg + F10 and report whether the error persists.

Comment: Whenever I try to change the n value it keeps giving x and y differ,I need n value from 1:1000

Comment: Try changing `plot(...,x=1:700,..)` to `plot(y=...,x=1:7000,...)`. Otherwise you need to open a new question as it seems to be another problem about your code.

Comment: If my answer helped you with your original matrix problem then you can accept it to indicate that the question is answered.

Comment: Oops, thought I did